# android - slide relativelayout to the side with static buttons

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

In my Activity I have two RelativeLayouts and two buttons. When you first open the Activity, you have to see a RelativeLayout and the buttons. Then you can slide the RelativeLayout to the right or to the left. The buttons don't move. While sliding, you see the other RelativeLayout below. After a completed slide you see the full RelativeLayout that was below.
How can I implement this in my Android application (min SDK version 14)?
Code examples are a big plus, but not necessary. It is ok to show me the way :)

Comment: What did you try already? Show your code please.

Comment: I tried it with `android:layout_below` and a transparent RelativeLayout, within two buttons.

Comment: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something called a navigation drawer which comes as a template in Android Studio. There are also many sliding menu libraries out there: https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=sliding specifically you might look at https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1429

If you want to do it from scratch, it'll go something like: have one layout, say a `Frame Layout` as your root. Then you add the two `Relative Layout`s and your buttons. Then you need to implement a `OnTouchListener` in your activity and set on the relative layout that can slide: when the `MotionEvent` is `ACTION_MOVE`, you need to calculate the difference between the last touch event and the current touch event and then you can call `translateX(dx)` on the sliding `relative layout` where `dx` is the calculated difference.